# does NHibernate 3.3 work with SQL Server 2012 Express?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, nhibernate, visual-studio-2012, nhibernate-mapping, sql-server-express

I cannot connect to SQL Server 2012 Express with NHibernate.

I get a

> Keyword not supported: 'server'.

exception. I get the same exception when using Data Source in lieu of Server. I recently switched DB's from MySql to SQL Server Express. I had no issues performing all CRUD. operations in MySql.

My `hibernate.cfg.xml` file is as follows:

```
<hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
     <session-factory>    
          <property name="connection.provider">NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider</property>
          <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2012Dialect</property>
          <property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.SqlClientDriver</property>    
          <property name="connection.connection_string">
                                              "Server=MyServer;
                                               Initial Catalog =MyDB;
                                               User Id=MyUserID;
                                               Password=MyPW;
                                               Convert Zero Datetime=True"

          </property>
          <property name="show_sql">true</property>
     </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Any help is most appreciated.

Comment: UPDATE:  MsSql2012Dialct is recognized when I upgraded to NHibernate 3.3, however the same error is thrown when compile reaches Server.

Comment: Ignore previous comment.  Update was applied to the question itself.

Comment: Well the answer resided in the mistaken "" placed around the information specified in the connection.connection_string tag.  I also needed to remove the declared schema in the hbm file.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the `Convert Zero Datetime` isn't supported? Otherwise, look into Hbm2DDLKeywords. You might have some classes with SQL Express reserved keywords.

Comment: Convert Zero Datetime does not affect behaviour.  Would you mind expounding on "Hbm2DDLKeywords" and "classes with SQL Express reserved keywords"?

Comment: Each database provider has certain keywords that are reserved. SQL Express might have keywords that aren't utilized in MySQL or SQL CE (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx). You might have an entity with a property using one of these keywords as it's name (for example: Desc, User, or Values). You can set the Hbm2DDLKeywords.keywords property to escape keywords. It creates backtick characters or brackets around the keywords when NHibernate generates the SQL.

Comment: If this is a non-production environment, try adding `<property name="hbm2ddl.keywords">auto-quote</property>` to your session-factory config and see if it resolves the issue.

Comment: The other valid values are `none` and `keywords`

Answer (score 0):

`Convert Zero Datetime` is MySQL connection string parameter only. If I add it to a SQL Server connection string I get "Keyword not supported: 'convert zero datetime'" and I'm not sure why your error message says that server is not supported but I think that removing `Convert Zero Datetime` from the connection string will fix the problem.

The connection string parameters have aliases and I think you can mix and match but for the record my SQL Server connection strings are usually of the form

```
Server=myserver;Database=mydatabase;Uid=myuser;Pwd=mysecretpassword;
```